# Accessing an element in an array within an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, for-loop

Pastebin of index.html: http://pastebin.com/g8WpX6Wn (this works but with some broken img links & no css).

Zip file if you want to see whole project:

I'm trying to dynamically change the contents of a div when I click an image. The image has it's respective id (the first index in the inner array) within the first inner array there's another array (index 3). I want to populate my div (id="articleLinks") with those links using JQuery when the image is clicked.

**JavaScript & JQuery:**

The tube array. *Note: the first index of each element in tubeArray is the ID & the news articles aren't linked to anything particular. Only interested in tubeArray[0] & tubeArray[4]

```
 var tubeArray = [
            ['UQ', -27.495134, 153.013502, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/uZ2SWWDt8Wg",  
                [
                ["example.com", "Brisbane students protest university fee hikes"],
                ["example.com", "Angry protests over UQ student union election"],
                ]
            ],
            ['New York', 40.715520, -74.002036, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/JG0wmXyi-Mw",
                [
                ["example.com" , "NY taxpayers’ risky Wall Street bet: Why the comptroller race matters"]
                ]
            ],
            ['To The Skies', 47.09399, 15.40548, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/tfEjTgUmeWw", 
                [
                ["example.com","Battle for Kobane intensifies as Islamic State uses car bombs, Syrian fighters execute captives"],
                ["example.com","Jihadists take heavy losses in battle for Syria's Kobane"]
                ]
            ],
            ['Fallujah', 33.101509, 44.047308, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/V2EOMzZsTrE", 
                [
                ["example.com","Video captures family cat saving California boy from dog attack"],
                ["example.com","Fines of £20,000 for dogs that chase the postman"]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

A for loop which goes through each element in tubeArray then assigns *id* to the first index. Also an image that calls the function *myFunctionId* which takes the parameter *this.id*.

```
for (i = 0; i < tubeArray.length; i++) {
    var id = tubeArray[i][0];

    //other code

    '<img src="img.png" onclick="myFunctionId(this.id);" id="' + id + '">' +

    //other code
}

function myFunctionId (id) {
        journal = id; 
        alert(journal) //just a test

        //I want to search through tubeArray with the id and find the matching inner array. 

        //I then want to loop through the innerArray and append to my html a link using JQuery.
        for (j = 0; i < innerArray.length; j++){
            //supposed to get "www.linkX.com"
            var $link = ;
            //supposed to get "titleX"
            var $title = ; 

            //change the content of <div id="articleLinks">
            $('#articleLinks').append('<a href=$link>$title</a><br>');
       }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="articleLinks">
    <a href="http:/www.google.com">Example Link</a><br>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried to simplify & cut out as much as I can so it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

probably this might help: make yourself a map like

```
var tubeArray = [
   [                                  // tubeArray[0]
     'id',                            // tubeArray[0][0]
     int,                             // tubeArray[0][1]
     int,                             // tubeArray[0][2]
     [                                // tubeArray[0][3]
        [                             // tubeArray[0][3][0]
           "www.link1.com",           // tubeArray[0][3][0][0]
           "title1"                   // tubeArray[0][3][0][1]
        ],  
        [                             // tubeArray[0][3][1]
            "www.link2.com",          // tubeArray[0][3][1][0]
            "title2"                  // tubeArray[0][3][1][1]
        ]
     ]
   ],
```

etc.
don't know whether this helps, but four dimensional arrays are brain-breaking ....

**[edit]**

... and thus go for a more OO like approach:

```
var tubeArray = [
    'id' : {                          // tubeArray[id] or tubeArray.id
     'a': int,                        // tubeArray.id.a
     'b': int,                        // tubeArray.id.b
     'entries': [                     // tubeArray.id.entries
        {                             // tubeArray.id.entries[0]
          'url': "www.link1.com",     // tubeArray.id.entries[0].url
          'title': "title1"           
        },  
        {                             // tubeArray.id.entries[1]
            'url': "www.link2.com",   // tubeArray.id.entries[1].url
            'title': "title2"         ...
        }
     ]
  ] ,
```

Comment: It helps me visualize it better, but I don't know how to solve the problem. I want to be able to search for the id in tubeArray.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to loop over `tubeArray` then go 4 deep and loop over the Array of Arrays at that level. Of course, you loop over those inner Arrays and get Elements `0` and `1`.

```
$.each(tubeArray, function(z, o){
  $.each(o[4], function(i, a){
    $.each(a, function(n, v){
      $('#articleLinks').append("<a href='"+v[0]+"'>"+v[1]+'</a>'); // use CSS to break lines
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You did not concatenate the Strings correctly either. Imagine the outer quotes just disappearing. This is JavaScript, not PHP. Double quotes do not interpret code, I'm just using them to hold the single quote mark on each side of the href value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand. Am I supposed to just use single quotes (') only?

Edit: I also didn't mention that in my original string that the index is 4. So I assume in your solution it's:

"var i= **4** ,l=tubeArray.length; i<l; i+= **5** " instead?

Comment: That's okay. You can use either. The only time I use double quotes is if I'm putting single quotes inside of them, like when I'm creating a String of HTML. I do the same thing in PHP. Of course, you don't have to concatenate single variables or Array Elements when using double quotes in PHP.

Comment: You need to give us your real code, or at least the same schematic next time. Hold on.

Comment: hi @PHPglue, thanks for your patiences thus far.

My entire index page is at http://pastebin.com/g8WpX6Wn (-css, and images). Essentially, you press on a node and a youtube video comes, the first broken image link is the one which should list the articles in tubeArray.

Comment: Sounds like a different question.